# DAX Today wasn't recognized

Tags: dax

In the Power BI I have a DAX function called `fnCreateCalendar` to create a Calendar dataset. I try to expand it a little bit to add some new atributes like `today` or calculate some month differences.

Unfortunately the code below return the error 'An error occure in the "query.Expression.Error. The name 'TODAY' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly'. Please help - I am new to DAX.

```
(StartDate as date, EndDate as date)=>

let
    ...

    // the code below throws an error
    CurrentYearMonthNumber = Table.AddColumn(myTable, "CurrentYearMonthNumber",
        TODAY()
    )
in
    CurrentYearMonthNumber
```

Comment: That's not a DAX function, it's M (also called "Power Query" or "Query Editor")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a DAX function (you can't create custom DAX function), the query editor uses M.
The equivalent of today() in M is:

```
# Returns a datetime
DateTime.LocalNow()
#if you need a date use Date.From()
Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
```

Comment: Another question - how to use SWITCH function in M? Is there any documentation for the generic M functions?

Comment: here you can find the M documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/, M does not have the switch function and you will have to use IF, here is something about a custom made switch function https://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/02/15/generic-switch-function-query-editor-in-power-bi-and-power-query/